# Sharable Controls/Views in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

Is it possible to design a view and use it for all platforms in Xamarin. Any available control library that are not platform specific and can be shared across all platforms in xamarin?. How can we maximum reuse the UI? Please help.

Comment: Check out MvvmCross. It is coming with a limited cross-platform UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present you have to create the UI for each platform independently. This is one of the great benefits of Xamarin as users get the platform specific experience for their device not a generic UI across all.

Answer (score 7):

Use the **[Xamarin.Forms](http://xamarin.com/forms)** API to quickly build shared screens for iOS, Android and Windows Phone.
The interface for the CRM app above is written using 100% shared C#.

Tutorial **[here](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/xaml-for-xamarin-forms/)**

Sample application with 1 UI which is shared among all 3 platforms is **[here](http://developer.xamarin.com/samples/XAMLSamples/)**

Still Xaml auto intellisense is not supported in Visual Studio as xamarin.forms might be still in beta phase and will have that support very soon.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Xamarin 3 has just introduced a cross-platform UI framework called Xamarin.Forms. It has a limited subset of controls right now, but it works across Android, iOS, and Windows Phone.

Comment: This should be marked as the accepted answer as the current one is now obsolete in the advent of Xamarin.Forms ( http://xamarin.com/forms ).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but I wanted to add this for reference purposes.

There is an open source project on Github with extensive examples of developing custom UI controls by way of extending the core offering within Xamarin.Forms:

https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs

This is a fantastic resource and has helped me greatly in understanding the underlying architecture of the Xamarin.Forms library.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late for the party but here it go:

You can use the Xamarin.Forms and develop it all in XAML.

It is still a new technology so you may have some cons like:

You default interface may be limited while using some specific platform features like: Material Design for Android. Or some swift specific functions.

So my recommendation:

- Use Xamarin.Forms if you want to save development time
- Use specific Xamarin.Droid and Xamarin.iOS if you want to add different features between android and iOS UI.
- Use specific Xamarin.Droid and Xamarin.iOS of you want to separate in UI and Application Layer.